# Stub doesn't return a value

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm using Mocha as test runner, Chai for assertion and Sinon.
I'm having trouble using sinon, I have the following function that I want to test in PrestigeQuoteService.js file

```
  find: function (criteria) {
    return PrestigeQuote.find(criteria)
      .populate('client')
      .populate('vehicle')
      .populate('quoteLogs');
  },
```

and here is my test case

```
  describe('find()', function () {
    describe('prestige quote found', function () {
      before(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        var mockChain = {
          populate: function () {
            return this;
          }
        };
        sandbox
          .stub(PrestigeQuote, 'find').returns(mockChain);
      });

      it('should return a particular quote', function (done) {
        PrestigeQuoteService.find({id: 1}, function (err, result) {
          result.should.exist;
          done();
        });
      });

      after(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
      });
    });
  });
```

yet I get this error, even thought I have done() and should return value by default.

```
 Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a return in mockChain

```
 describe('prestige quote found', function () {
      before(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        var err = null;
        var mockChain = {
          populate: function () {
            return this;
          },
          return:function () {
            return {};
          }
        };
        sandbox
          .stub(PrestigeQuote, 'find').returns(mockChain);
      });

      it('should return a particular  prestige quote', function (done) {
       PrestigeQuoteService.find({id: 1}, function (result) {
          result.should.exist;
        });
        done();
      });

      after(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use time out inside it() function  .

```
describe('find()', function () {
    describe('prestige quote found', function () {
      before(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        var mockChain = {
          populate: function () {
            return this;
          }
        };
        sandbox
          .stub(PrestigeQuote, 'find').returns(mockChain);
      });

      it('should return a particular quote', function (done) {
         this.timeout(50000);
        PrestigeQuoteService.find({id: 1}, function (err, result) {
          result.should.exist;
          done();
        });
      });

      after(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I don't think the time is the problem, I think the function doesn't return the object, I tried to add return in mockChain and still doesn't work